# LeadBolt Ads appear on keypad

Tags: ios7, ads, leadbolt

i'm using LeadBolt framework in my app.i'm facing problem while ad appear,Ad appear under keypad as show in image.

[image]

please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
 [self.view endEditing: YES];

Comment: how can i load ad above keyboard?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keywindow addSubView:yourAd]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keywindow bringSubViewToFront:YourAd];